# Using Jackson to map object from specific node in JSON tree

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is it possible to have Jackson's `ObjectMapper` unmarshall only from a specific node (and 'down') in a JSON tree?

The use case is an extensible document format. I want to walk the tree, and then publish the current path to an extensible set of plugins, to see if the user is using and plugins that know what to do with that part of the document.

I'd like for plugin authors to not have to deal with the low-level details of `JsonNode` or the streaming API; instead, just be passed some context and a specific `JsonNode`, and then be able to use the lovely and  convenient `ObjectMapper` to unmarshall an instance of their class, considering the node passed as the root of the tree.

Comment: Sounds exactly like this: http://martinfowler.com/articles/refactoring-document-load.html#CreatingObjectsDeepInTheDocumentStructure

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Consider the following JSON:

```json
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "address": {
    "street": "21 2nd Street",
    "city": "New York",
    "postalCode": "10021-3100",
    "coordinates": {
      "latitude": 40.7250387,
      "longitude": -73.9932568
    }
  }
}
```

And consider you want to parse the `coordinates` node into the following Java class:

```
public class Coordinates {

    private Double latitude;

    private Double longitude;
    
    // Default constructor, getters and setters omitted
}
```

To do it, parse the whole JSON into a [`JsonNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) with [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html):

```java
String json = "{\"firstName\":\"John\",\"lastName\":\"Doe\",\"address\":{\"street\":"
            + "\"21 2nd Street\",\"city\":\"New York\",\"postalCode\":\"10021-3100\","
            + "\"coordinates\":{\"latitude\":40.7250387,\"longitude\":-73.9932568}}}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(json);
```

Then use [JSON Pointer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901) to query the `coordinates` node and use [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) to parse it into the `Coordinates` class:

```java
JsonNode coordinatesNode = node.at("/address/coordinates");
Coordinates coordinates = mapper.treeToValue(coordinatesNode, Coordinates.class);
```

JSON Pointer is a path language to traverse JSON. For more details, check the [RFC 6901](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901). It is available in Jackson since the version 2.3.

Comment: That's exactly what I was after! I'll award the bounty once I've had a chance to implement it.

Comment: I would say `node.get("address")` is simpler/more efficent for this case.

Comment: @shmosel Of course it is. But the point here is the JSON Path that can be used to query for a node. The JSON I provided as example is really simple and we cannot see the advantages of using JSON Path.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin, oops I didn't realize that was a contrived example.

Comment: The answer was updated with a slightly more complex example.