# Extract specific node of JSON response in RESTEasy Client

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, resteasy, jackson2

I'm retrieving a JSON string from an API using a RESTEasy client. The JSON payload looks something like this:

```json
{
  "foo1" : "",
  "foo2" : "",
  "_bar" : {
    "items" : [
      { "id" : 1 , "name" : "foo", "foo" : "bar" },
      { "id" : 2 , "name" : "foo", "foo" : "bar" },
      { "id" : 3 , "name" : "foo", "foo" : "bar" },
      { "id" : 4 , "name" : "foo", "foo" : "bar" }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now I'd like to extract only the `items` node for object mapping. What is the best way to intercept the JSON response body and modify it to have `items` as root node?

I'm using the [RESTEasy proxy framework](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-beta-3/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html#d4e2049) for my API methods.

The REST client code:

```java
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target("https://"+server);
target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
client.register(new ClientAuthHeaderRequestFilter(getAccessToken()));
MyProxyAPI api = target.proxy(MyProxyAPI.class);
MyDevice[] result = api.getMyDevice();
```

RESTEasy proxy interface:

```java
public interface MyProxyAPI {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/device")
    public MyDevice[] getMyDevices();

    ...
}
```

Comment: Convert to the Javascript object and retrieve it as a Object.

Comment: Is it important that `items` be the root, or just that you don't want to map any other elements of the message? Doing a quick look at RestEasy docs, you're using automatic marshalling/unmarshalling to Java beans, through a JAXB provider?

Comment: @dbreaux Yes, I just don't want to map any other elements. See my edit of the OP for a simplified implementation code. I could of course register a provider to change the message body but I wonder how the implementation of such provider would look like.

Comment: When the mapping is done automatically, why add the complexity of preprocess the response and not simply extract the objects afterwards?

Comment: I think, I would need to model the complete Json structure in java, which i consider messy. In reality there is a whole lot more objects around my "items" node.

Comment: Depends on you finally, but have in mind that when preprocessing the response you also store model knowledge - as processing information. It would save you from storing the model knowlede persistently but model changes will be harder to comprehend as you have to understand changes in the process rather than in the structure.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same desire to not have to define complex Java classes for messages that contain way more fields than I care about. In my JEE server (WebSphere), Jackson is the underlying JSON implementation, which does appear to be an option with RESTEasy. Jackson has an [@JsonIgnoreProperties](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) annotation that can ignore unknown JSON fields:

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@XmlType
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class JsonBase {}
```

I don't know if other JSON implementations have a similar capability, but it certainly seems a natural use-case.

(I also wrote a [blog post](https://dougbreaux.github.io/2016/03/04/websphere8.5-json-rest-client.html) with this and some other JAX-RS techniques relevant to my WebSphere environment.)

Comment: It's a nice solution, but it might not work for the situation described by the OP. The `items` node is a child of `_bar` and not a child of the root node.

Comment: You can still do this by defining wrapper classes which have almost nothing in them. In my case, this was better than the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [`ReaderInterceptor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ReaderInterceptor.html) and use Jackson to manipulate your JSON:

```java
public class CustomReaderInterceptor implements ReaderInterceptor {

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public Object aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorContext context) 
                      throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(context.getInputStream());
        JsonNode items = tree.get("_bar").get("items");
        context.setInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(mapper.writeValueAsBytes(items)));
        return context.proceed();
    }
}
```

Then register the [`ReaderInterceptor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ReaderInterceptor.html) created above in your [`Client`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html):

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.register(CustomReaderInterceptor.class);
```

Comment: Actually, one of your answers to another question might be a simple solution to this too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38352932/796761

Comment: Your older solution linked by dbreaux (getting the JSON and accessing the desired node via the Jackson tree) is what I was doing as a workaround until now. This of course won't work with the proxy framework. I will try the interceptor. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinPeter Sure! Try it an let me know if it works for you :)