# Correct way to map JSON to Java Object

Tags: java, json

Im trying to map some json elements to a java object but cant seem to figure out the correct way. Theres obviously loads of examples online on how to map json to pojos but I have a big JSON string and I only want to map a few keys in the JSON String to build up an object...

```
{
"glossary": {
    "title": "example glossary",
    "GlossDiv": {
        "title": "S",
        "GlossList": {
            "GlossEntry": {
                "ID": "SGML",
                "SortAs": "SGML",
                "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                "Acronym": "SGML",
                "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                "GlossDef": {
                    "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                    "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                },
                "GlossSee": "markup"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

lets say I only want the title and GlossEntry: id, SortAs and Abbrev,

What's the cleanest why to map it to a pojo with only those fields without having to map the whole json to an object and get those elements

Comment: You would first have to choose a mapper. They don't all have the same capabilities. But I doubt you'll find one that allows you to skip the intermediate GlossDiv and GlossList objects, unless you customize the mapper by writing low-level parsing code yourself. Ans if you're ready to do that, then you could simply use a generic JSON parser (i.e. returning JSONObjects, or Maps), and extract the information from that.

Comment: Hey cheers, thats what I was thinking but wasn't sure if it was the correct approach. Maybe to resourceful to convert the whole json string to an object and get the elements as needed

Comment: Don't optimize until you have a performance problem, and you've proven that this performance problem comes from parsing that JSON. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: So you're saying convert the whole JSON to an object and get elements needs be?

Comment: Have you ever considered using Jackson? Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38352932/1426227).

Comment: Thats exactly the answer I was looking for :) Cheers

Comment: You only need to annotate your POJO with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`. I can write a tailored answer for you.

Comment: If my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38352932/1426227) was useful, please consider to upvote it. I also wrote a tailored [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42346936/1426227) to your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are open to use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), a popular JSON parser for Java, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38352932/1426227) may give you some insights. Here's a tailored solution for your question.

First define a class as following to hold the values:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class GlossaryEntry {
    
    @JsonProperty("ID")
    private String id;
    
    @JsonProperty("SortAs")
    private String sortAs;
    
    @JsonProperty("Abbrev")
    private String abbrev;
    
    // Constructor, getters and setters omitted
}
```

Then parse the whole JSON into a [`JsonNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) with [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html):

```java
String json = "{\"glossary\":{\"title\":\"example glossary\",\"GlossDiv\":{\"title\":\"S\",\"GlossList\":{\"GlossEntry\":{\"ID\":\"SGML\",\"SortAs\":\"SGML\",\"GlossTerm\":\"Standard Generalized Markup Language\",\"Acronym\":\"SGML\",\"Abbrev\":\"ISO 8879:1986\",\"GlossDef\":{\"para\":\"A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.\",\"GlossSeeAlso\":[\"GML\",\"XML\"]},\"GlossSee\":\"markup\"}}}}}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(json);
```

Use [JSON Pointer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901) to query for the `GlossEntry` node and finally use [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) to parse it into a `GlossaryEntry` instance:

```java
JsonNode node = tree.at("/glossary/GlossDiv/GlossList/GlossEntry");
GlossaryEntry glossaryEntry = mapper.treeToValue(node, GlossaryEntry.class);
```

[JSON Pointer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901) is a path language to traverse JSON. For more details, check the [RFC 6901](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901). It is available in Jackson since the version 2.3.

Comment: Hey, this Is an excellent example, but what if there was an ''ID" also in a total different node i.e the root "glossary" also had an ID...again cheers for the reply :)

Comment: @rogger2016 Well, this solution is intended to address the situation you provided in your question. Do you also need the `ID` of the root node (if it exists)?

Comment: Yes, I probably going to come across that soon. Would the annotation signature change for example if ID was in different node "glossA/ID" another annotation would be "GlossB/ID"....not sure

Comment: @rogger2016 I'm not sure if I understand your new requirement. But you may be able to get that value using JSON Path. Also, you may consider asking a new question, adding all the relevant details :)

Answer (score 1):

With googles [gson library](https://github.com/google/gson) you can map the json to a generic JsonElement. From there you can access fields and traverse subobjects as you like.

```
JsonElement elem = new JsonParser.parse(input);
```

This gets more complicated the more fields you require. I'd suggest building a deserialization DTO providing the right object hierarchy. You can then use standard mapping approaches to map your json. 
In a second step you can map this DTO to your own domain model. 
Projects like [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/) make this task fairly easy.